# Colour background with styleInterval() of shiny Date datatable

Tags: r, shiny, formatting, dt

I am trying to apply background colour to a datatable of 'date' information:
 green = up to date, yellow = out of date, red = REALLY out of date.
Basically like the 'style a full table' heatmap example found here: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html

My code looks approximately like this;

```
library(wakefield)
library(shiny)
library(DT)

backlogTbl <- r_data_frame(n = 5,
 date_stamp,
 date_stamp,
 date_stamp,
 date_stamp) %>%
r_na(prob=.25)

backlogDT <- datatable(backlogTbl) %>%
              formatStyle(names(backlogTbl), 
                  backgroundColor = styleInterval(Sys.Date() - days(c(7,2)), 
                  c("red", "yellow", "green")))
```

When I run this every non-null background is green instead of green/yellow/or red depending on the value but when I compare individual cells to my breakpoints i.e.

```
backlogTbl[1,1] < Sys.Date() - days(c(7,2))
```

I can see that the values *are* within the intervals I've defined.

If I pass the iris dataset through my code it formats fine which makes me suspect that the problem is that it's date time data? I feel like I'm missing something obvious...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is currently supported, and I created a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/495) for it.

One workaround is to create a column that holds integer versions of the dates and have your style based on that. Then hide the integer column

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("DateDemo"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput('tbl'),
      width = 10,
      height = "800px")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$tbl <-
    renderDT({
      splitDate <- as.Date("2018-02-02")
      data_frame(ExampleDate = as.Date(c("2018-01-01","2019-01-01"))) %>%
        mutate(ExampleDateInt = as.integer(ExampleDate)) %>% #make column with integer dates
        datatable(options=list(columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(2))))) %>% #hide the integer column
        formatStyle(columns = "ExampleDate",
                    valueColumns = "ExampleDateInt",
                    backgroundColor = styleInterval(as.integer(splitDate),c("#FB717E","#89EC6A"))) #format based on the integer column
    }) 
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```